# Codeigniter: Override variable in auto-loaded config file

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following:

> config/email.php

```
$config['protocol']  = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = "xxxxxx";
$config['smtp_user'] = "xxxxxx";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "xxxxxx";
$config['smtp_port'] = xx;   
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; 
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

So in most cases, I'm sending HTML with plain-text alternative emails. This config works perfectly.

Now in one special case, I'm wanting to send a plain-text email so I need to override that setting to:`$config['mailtype'] = 'text';`

How can I do that? I tried specifying a new config array and loading the library again but it still sends as HTML:

```
 $email_config = Array(
        'mailtype'  => 'text'
 );

 $this->load->library('email', $email_config);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call initialize when you don't load from a config file.

```
$this->email->initialize($email_config);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```